# Why is my cactus limping?

Tags: cactus

[image: cactus]

Not sure why it's been limping, the baby one also started limping and died recently. The bottom is a bit yellow but not rotten yet. Not sure how to care for it not that it's so tall

Comment: Your photo is very small. The plant looks like it needs more light as a first suggestion. Please look for some cactus care information online. there is much out there.

Answer (score 1):

Cactus generally require lots of sunlight everyday. The only way to "fix" this plant is to put it in a place where it can get a minimum of 6 hours of sunlight. It will never look normal.